# What does "supply values for the following parameters mean in command line?"

Tags: powershell, directory, command, cat

So inside of my terminal, I created a text file inside a directory (cat > fnames.txt). My initial goal was to write some data into said file. After creating fnames.txt, the following information showed up after trying to append data to the file using (cat >> fnames.txt):

`cmdlet Get-Content at command pipeline position 1`

`Supply values for the following parameters:`

`Path[0]:`

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyL1n.png)

Does anyone know the reason of this and what it means?

Comment: It doesn't look like `unix` as you tagged

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Sorry that was a mistake. The tag I meant to put was Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The command `cat` is in Powershell an alias to `Get-Content`. The cmdlet [reads information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3) from somewhere. The error message means that `Get-Content` does not have an idea from where you want it to get data, so it asks you.